# Managing long strings (over 100k chars) in Python

Tags: python

I'm working on some challenges in Python (www.pythonchallenge.com/) where I need to find sequences of characters in a rather long string of seemingly random characters.

I've worked out most of the problem (i.e. coming up with a function to extract the sequence I'm looking for), but I can't apply it to my string because it's too long (a bit over 100k characters).

I've tried inputing it as a regular string with the classic :

```
string = "I'm a lumberjack and I'm OK I sleep all night and I work all day, He's a lumberjack and he's OK, He sleeps all night and he works all day etc etc"
```

Jupyter Lab doesn't like that one bit. The cell with the input just starts working but doesn't seem to end.

Interestingly, I've checked memory/processor and everything seems fine.

Any ideas as to how to deal with this ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Are you sure your function is actually finishing?  Please show the code

Comment: The code works. I've tested it out with a short sample and it works without issue. My problem is declaring the variable.

Comment: A sample code with a working example will help us help you.

Comment: it looks like a [possible] restriction by Jupyter Lab, not python. i.e. you can easily read from a file and process a much longer strings than 100K chars. So try reading it from a file or change the IDE

Comment: "Jupyter Lab doesn't like that one bit" is not very specific. What error are you getting and how do we reproduce it? I've pasted your example line into python RELP and all went fine...

Comment: That's the thing. I'm not getting any error. I'll try reading from a file and if that doesn't work i'll upload the text for reproduction.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the suggestions !

For the record it seems seems to be a limitation on the way strings can be declared in Jupyter. A simple file.read() function proved to be spectacularly more efficient.

```
file = open("string.txt", "r")
string = file.read()
```

Thanks a lot